# Is there a way to create a website that embeds multiple tabs?

Tags: reactjs, google-search

I have this idea for a website, where you can open multiple 'tabs' (like a web-browser tab) in one page, for comfortable multipage browsing. How should I go about developing it and what technologies should I use?
Here is a simple design of the website I have in mind.

[image: page design]

I would appreciate any advice! I'm a beginner who just learned React, Looking for general guidance here :)

I tried to embed a [Google Programmable Search Engine](https://programmablesearchengine.google.com/about/) into a React component, Idk why but I couldn't get it to work. Also, a problem I encountered with the search engine is that opening a website takes over my page instead of the website existing inside a div like I want it to.

Comment: `<iframe>` is the tag you're looking for. But go check every single one of those websites' terms of use. I bet each one has specific policies for when and how you're allowed to embed their site, and if you don't follow it they'll probably just block you.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Thank you, I read that <iframe> should not be used, I'll read more on the whys and try it then.